# Is it possible to push a index.html to heroku?

Tags: php, html, heroku

I develop a pure front-end app with an index-file called index.html. Everytime I push to heroku, i need to rename it index.php, in order to tell heroku to use php. Is there another way to declare what type of server I want? So that I get to keep my file as an html-file?

Comment: You cannot directly serve static files, but you can manage that by simple node.js app. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564500/is-it-possible-to-push-a-index-html-to-heroku/23564786#23564786)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also just drop an empty `composer.json` into your project to make Heroku treat your project as a PHP project.

The preference of `index.php` over `index.html` comes from the default `DirectoryIndex` directive that Apache uses on Heroku; it has nothing to do with your browser. To change it, you could drop a `.htaccess` with `DirectoryIndex index.html` into your application.

If you just want raw performance for your static site, it's also probably a good idea to use Nginx. The default configuration should be reasonable for your purposes so add a `Procfile` with `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx` to your project along with an empty `composer.json` (and no `index.php`) and you're good to go.

Also see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that simple [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) app with [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/);

Let say your project folder has a sub folder called `public`,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port, function() { 
    console.log('Your files will be served through this web server')
});
```

Save this code in app.js, put your static files under `public` folder, and prepare your `Procfile`

Final folder structure will be;

```
yourproject
--public/
----your staticfiles
--app.js
--Procfile
```

`Procfile` will be;

```
web: node app.js
```

And deploy your project. When you request your static files like; `.../index.html`, `index.html` will be served under public folder

Answer (score 0):

Add a empty file called index.php, this will be used by heroku, though, index.html will be prioritised by browsers.